Apache site will not load via URL
I had two working websites until I realized over the weekend that my server was running Ubuntu 23.04 which had no apparent easy upgrade to 24.04. So I backed up my web files and site config files and did a clean install of Ubuntu. I have been trying to get my sites back up since (Sunday 8th of December).I am currently working on getting one of them up, once it is up I'll work on the other one.
I am able to load my site locally via local IP address or remotely via public IP. However, I am unable to load the site via URL.
My config file is as follows -- the name of which is deletedforsec.us.conf
ServerName www.deletedforsec.us

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@deletedforsec.us
        ServerName deletedforsec.us
        ServerAlias www.deletedforsec.us
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/deletedforsec.us
        ErrorDocument 404 /404Error.shtml

        <Directory /var/www/html/deletedforsec.us>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AddType text/html .shtml
                AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =deletedforsec.us [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.deletedforsec.us
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent] </VirtualHost>

I have disabled the default site (sudo a2dissite 000-default)
I have enabled the site I am working on (sudo a2ensite deletedforsec.us.conf)
I have enabled url rewrite (sudo a2enmod rewrite)
I have enabled includes (sudo a2enmod include)
Can somebody please tell me where I have errored or what I need to do to resolve this issue?

FYI:  There was an easy upgrade path from 23.04 to 23.10 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManticUpgrades) as long as 23.10 wasn't EOL; then from 23.10 to 24.04 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades); but 23.04 being part of the two year LTS development cycle cannot skip a release. Documentation (I feel) makes that pretty clear; refer release notes, announcements & EOL warning notices relating to the release.

I searched for a couple hours. Every command I did ran to try to upgrade found 24.04 as the new update. 23.10 went EOL iin July probably why I couldn't update.

Ubuntu 23.04 tells you it was the 2023-April release (easy given the year.month nature of the release) so adding 9 months to 2023-April tells you it reached EOL in Jan 2024 even if you don't know actual day of month.. You have a further six months after that before release-upgrade path is completely gone (next release is EOL); so all you needed was the 23.04 & simple math to calculate the windows of when you could upgrade. The year.month format allows you to plan.
